# Stash Parse Order Issues

Tags: stash, low-search, parse-order, parse

Im pretty sure the problem here is the parse order, but I'm struggling to figure out where the issue is.

I have a page with the following on it:

```
{exp:stash:set name="market_ids" parse_tags="yes"}
{exp:query sql="select GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id SEPARATOR '|') as market_ids from exp_channel_data where channel_id=3 AND field_id_12 LIKE CONCAT('%', DAYNAME(from_unixtime({exp:stash:delivery_day})), '%')" parse="inward"}
    {market_ids}
{/exp:query}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Then further on in the page I have the following:

```
{exp:low_search:results limit="{exp:stash:paging default='12' type='snippet'}" channel="products" status="not closed" child:cf_product_market="{exp:stash:market_ids}" child:cf_product_delivery_zone="{fn_zone_id}" paginate="bottom"}
....
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

The Paging stash entry is set on another page with scope="site" and type="snippet" and that works fine, however the {exp:stash:market_ids} is just not being recognised in the tag. I've output the value to the page and its definitely got data in the entry.

I've tried adding parse="inward" to the {exp:low_search:results} tag, but that doesn't appear to make any difference either.

Is there something else that I need to do to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, So I had to wrap the entire call in a {exp:stash:parse process='end'} tag and then call the values with just {stash:market_ids}.

Now seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Is the stash {exp:stash:market_ids} rendering outside of your low_search? Thats probably a good place to start.

I would also try putting

```
{exp:stash:set name="market_ids" parse_tags="yes"}
{exp:query sql="select GROUP_CONCAT(entry_id SEPARATOR '|') as market_ids from exp_channel_data where channel_id=3 AND field_id_12 LIKE CONCAT('%', DAYNAME(from_unixtime({exp:stash:delivery_day})), '%')" parse="inward"}
    {market_ids}
{/exp:query}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

In an embedded file and retrieving it with a process='start'.

```
{exp:stash:embed:folder:file_name process="start"}
```

Hope thats helpful, not completely convinced. Parsing can be confusing.